# Loading a TModel3D on Android Release version

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

My Delphi FMX 3D application runs fine on Win32 and iOS.
On Android, in Debug mode it works, but when I switch to Release mode, an embedded TModel3d will not show.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

- Create a FMX 3d application
- add a Light and a TModel3d.
- Select the model and edit MeshCollection.
- Load a 3d model. I used a Wavefront .OBJ file, but the result is the same with Collada models.

The model shows on Android Debug version, but not on Release. Not sure why...

In Release mode the model is there. I can see the vertices in MeshCollection[0].Data.Points. But it doesn't show. I tried to delete the model material. With this the model shows in red color on all platforms, but nothing on Android Release..

iOS and Windows are fine...

Using Delphi 11.2 patch 1. This worked in previous Delphi versions (10.x).

Any ideas ?

Sample project at
https://github.com/omarreis/vsop2013/blob/master/Documents/testLoadModel.zip